# React Native: is it possible to force characters in TextInput to be capitals?

Tags: react-native, textinput, react-native-textinput, autocapitalize

I'm using a `TextInput` in my React Native app with `autocapitalize: 'characters'`. It autocapitalizes all characters, but I'm still able to press the shift key (iOS), which switches to lowercase. I want to prevent the user from being able to switch to lowercase. Does anyone know if there's a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

One of the workarounds could be following

```
export default function MyUpperCaseText() {
  const [text, setText] = React.useState("")
  return <TextInput value={text} onChangeText={(text)=>setText(text.toUpperCase())} />
}
```

Comment: Well this adds duplicate characters if user enters alphabet in lower case.